# Nginx in docker container doesn't catch any request

Tags: docker, nginx

I ahve a react app which I've deployed into a docker container, from the image nginx:alpine.

When I access the URL, I don't get anything when doing docker logs -f nginx for some reason. (basically, I think nginx doesn't catch any request) and the browser says "Unable to connect".

This is my first deployment so I might be doing something wrong :)

Here's the nginx entry from docker-compose

```
nginx:
    container_name: best-nginx
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/default.conf
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    ports:
      - "443:443"
```

default.conf

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name myservername.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /keycloak {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:28080/;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Dockerfile

```
# develop stage
FROM node:18-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./public ./public
COPY ./src ./src

# build stage
FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.23.1-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker logs -f nginx

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/10/07 09:56:33 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2022/10/07 09:56:33 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.1
2022/10/07 09:56:33 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 
2022/10/07 09:56:33 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-48-generic
2022/10/07 09:56:33 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2022/10/07 09:56:33 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022/10/07 09:56:33 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
```

why does my nginx not catch any request and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config mounted to wrong path should be under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

```
- ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: Would you mind checking this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73986304/nginx-cannot-load-certificate-in-docker-container