# Nginx cannot load certificate in docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

So I'm trying to use nginx with a certbot certificate in a docker container, but I get this error, even though the file exists.

```
2022/10/07 11:08:47 [emerg] 15#15: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

The certificates were generated outside of the docker container and mounted into nginx (so I might've done it wrong).

```
nginx:
    container_name: best-nginx
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycerts:/etc/nginx/certs
    ports:
      - "443:443"
```

default.conf

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name myservername.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /keycloak {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:28080/;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Dockerfile

```
# develop stage
FROM node:18-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./public ./public
COPY ./src ./src

# build stage
FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.23.1-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

What I observed is that certbot generates 4 files, while I'm using only 2 in my default.conf

Could that be the root of my problem?

Thanks.

//Edit:
The files exist in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycerts but I can't access live/mycerts without root access. So I think they might be mapped weirdly?

Here's a ls -la in the docker container, in /etc/nginx/certs, and they look a bit strange.

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            45 Oct  7 10:20 cert.pem -> ../../archive/mycerts/cert1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            46 Oct  7 10:20 chain.pem -> ../../archive/mycerts/chain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            50 Oct  7 10:20 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/mycerts/fullchain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            48 Oct  7 10:20 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/mycerts/privkey1.pem
```

Comment: check  fullchain.pem and privkey.pem exist in  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycerts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mounting a folder with symbolic links, in you container you will get symbolic links that points to the same location, not real files.

So either you mount a directory with real cert files **recommended**

or mount `archive/mycerts:/etc` so symblic links points to real files inside the conatiner **not recommended**